# c - Pointer of array initialized in a function contains wrong values after returning

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, int

I'm facing an issue and I'm certainly doing something wrong.
I need to call a function that returns a pointer to an array of int but when after it returns, the values inside the array are wrong and some values are missing.

```
int* patternForFirstDigit(int digit) {
    int *pattern;
    pattern = (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1};

    switch (digit) {
        case 0:
            pattern = (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1};
            break;

        case 1:
            pattern = (int [6]){1,1,2,1,2,2};
            break;

        default:
            pattern = (int [6]){0,0,0,0,0,0};
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         printf("%i\n", pattern[i]);
    }

    return pattern;
}
```

In case of digit = 1, here's what's printed

```
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2
```

But after returning

```
int *pattern = patternForFirstDigit(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     printf("%i\n", pattern[i]);
}
```

here's what's printed

```
1, -1405451528, -1405449120, 366001
```

Do you have an idea of what's wrong ?

Thanks guys

PS : I'm using Xcode 4.6 and my project is using ARC but I'm pretty sure it's not the reason of my problem.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a temporary array.

Comment: This same "FAQ" gets asked about 20 times a day on SO.  Wish there was a way to prevent it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not return a pointer to an array created in a function. This array is no longer existing after a function returns, so your pointer points to some random, invalid place in a memory.

Allocate memory for a pointer (using `malloc()` for instance) and then return a pointer. This would also mean you'd need to free a pointer after you're done with it (with `free()`).

Pseudocode for this would be something like:

```
int* patternForFirstDigit(int digit) {
  int *pattern = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
  pattern[0] = 0;
  pattern[1] = 1;
  ...

  // Alternatively just create a local array and use a for-loop
  // to copy the contents to the pattern array.

  return pattern;
}

int *p = patternForFirstDigit(M);
// use p
free(p);
```

Comment: I did what you suggest but it still doesn't work : int *pattern = malloc(sizeof(int) * 6); pattern = (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1}; but when i return values are still wrong and i get this message when i try to free it malloc: *** error for object 0xbfffda9c: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: @Dave - you cannot assign a array to a pointer this way. You could use  on example: `pattern[0] = 0; pattern[1] = 1; ...`.

Comment: @kamituel OMG that's a pain. I've 10 case in my switch and I have 6 values in my array so I need to do pattern[n] = ...; 60 times ? Can't I initialize the array on one line like this format : {1,1,2,1,2,2} ?

Comment: @Dave - you can create a local array in a function and then, in a `for` loop, copy the contents to the `pattern`. This way `pattern`  will be valid when function returns.

Answer (score 1):

the

```
(int [6]){1,1,2,1,2,2};
```

is a local array defined in the function . so the data of the array could be erased when the function finish the execution. so that's why you get garbage values in your `printf`

1) Use `malloc` to allocate array instead

```
int* patternForFirstDigit(int digit) {
    int *pattern = malloc(6*sizeof(int));

    memcpy(pattern, (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1}, 6*sizeof(int));

    switch (digit) {
        case 0:
            memcpy(pattern, (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1}, 6*sizeof(int));
            break;

        case 1:
            memcpy(pattern, (int [6]){1,1,2,1,2,2};, 6*sizeof(int));
            break;

        default:
            memcpy(pattern, (int [6]){0,0,0,0,0,0}, 6*sizeof(int));
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         printf("%i\n", pattern[i]);
    }

    return pattern;
}
```

and some where in your code when the `pattern` became useless then free it with `free(pattern);`

2) Or use `static` in the definition of the array:

```
int* patternForFirstDigit(int digit) {
    int *pattern; int i;
    static int A[6]={1,1,1,1,1,1};
    static int B[6]={1,1,2,1,2,2};
    static int C[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    pattern = A;

    switch (digit) {
        case 0:
            pattern = A;
            break;

        case 1:
            pattern = B;
            break;

        default:
            pattern = C;
            break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         printf("%i\n", pattern[i]);
    }

    return pattern;
}
```

Comment: static doesn't work I get an Expected expression error. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: @Dave you are right it's a mistake in my code. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are returning a local variable. A local variable is a temporary one that is no longer available after its scope is gone. You may try the following:

```
int* patternForFirstDigit(int digit, int* pattern) {

    int* pattern1 = (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1};
int i;
    switch (digit) {
        case 0:
            pattern1 = (int [6]){1,1,1,1,1,1};
            break;

        case 1:
            pattern1 = (int [6]){1,1,2,1,2,2};
            break;

        default:
            pattern1 = (int [6]){0,0,0,0,0,0};
            break;
    }
memcpy(pattern,pattern1,6*sizeof(int));
    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         printf("%i\n", pattern[i]);
    }
    return pattern;
}
```

Then you may use it like:

```
pattern = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
pattern=patternForFirstDigit(1, pattern);
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     printf("%i\n", pattern[i]);
}
free(pattern);
```

Comment: DEFINETLY WRONG. fix your code, there is a risk to get downvoted

Comment: `pattern = malloc(...); pattern = (int [6])...` : You just leaked the memory from malloc, without fixing the problem. If you replaced the pattern assignments with copies into the allocated memory, that would be a better (but still poor) solution.